# Getting JSON data out of local scope in SWIFT 4

Tags: ios, json, scope, swift4, jsondecoder

So, I have been trying to make this code work for a couple of days and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

I am getting a JSON from the web and parsing it with Struct blocks.

The question is: I want to use the Dictionaries and Array from the JSON out of where I created de decode function.

Here is the code

```
import UIKit


struct  Currency_format: Decodable{
    var iso_code: String
    var example_format : String
    var decimal_digits : Int
    var decimal_separator : String
    var symbol_first : Bool
    var group_separator : String
    var currency_symbol : String
    var display_symbol : Bool
}

struct  Date_Format: Decodable{
    var format : String
}

struct Budgets: Decodable {
    var id : String
    var name: String
    var last_modified_on : String
    var first_month : String
    var last_month : String
    var date_format : Date_Format
    var currency_format : Currency_format
}

struct DataResponse : Decodable {
    var data : Data
}

struct Data : Decodable{
    var budgets : [Budgets]
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let accessToken = "1234"
    let authorizationRequestHeader = "https://www.somewhere.com=\(accessToken)"


    guard let url = URL(string: authorizationRequestHeader) else {
        print("Error")
        return
    }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (stringData, response, Error) in
        let testString =  try! dataResponse.decode(DataResponse.self, from:stringData!)
        print("Number of records: \(testString.data.budgets.count)")
        //THIS PRINT WORKS AS I WANT IT TO WORK. NOT PROBLEM HERE
        }.resume()

  print("Number of records: \(testString.data.budgets.count)") // BUT THE SAME CODE HERE, DOES NOT WORK AT ALL
```

Comment: Use a property instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do one thing, initialize `testString` just before the `viewDidLoad()`
Like :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let testString : DataResponse!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    let accessToken = "1234"
    let authorizationRequestHeader = "https://www.somewhere.com=\(accessToken)"


    guard let url = URL(string: authorizationRequestHeader) else {
        print("Error")
        return
    }
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: url) { (stringData, response, Error) in
        testString =  try! dataResponse.decode(DataResponse.self, from:stringData!)
        print("Number of records: \(testString.data.budgets.count)")

    }.resume()


print("Number of records: \(testString.data.budgets.count)")
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: The last `print` will still fail as it does in the original code. But that is simply because it's being called long before the data is ready.

Comment: Yeah, it worked but I needed to twike a little: self.testString =  try! JSONDecoder().decode(DataResponse.self, from:stringData!)

Comment: @ThiagoGonçalvesPinto Because your data is loaded asynchronously in the background via `URLSession`. Meanwhile, the result of the code in `viewDidLoad` keeps going and that last `print` is called long before the data is retrieved from the URL.

Answer (score 0):

JSON Decoder method does not work normally with snake_case keys available in your JSON. To work as excepted, in this case we have to use CodingKeys methodology.

Refer this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) for detailed info.

Comment: Sample Example:

struct Item : Decodable {

 let title:String,content:String,version:Int,created:Int32,modified:Int32,noteId:Int

  private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
    case title,content,version,created,modified,noteId = "note_id"
  }


}
//

Inside response completion

do {
       let items = try JSONDecoder().decode([Item].self, from: data)
       print(items)
}
catch {
    print(error)
 }